# How to call the same task twice simultaneously

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task

I need to call the same task twice simultaneously on a button event. When the user presses a button the task is called, so if they press it multiple times it needs to be called multiple times. The user selects a radio button and then clicks the button to do something, so I need to alter the specific object related to the radio button. (UI locks until task is finished or a different radio button is selected) It is critical that my user is allowed to press the button another time if another radio button is selected.

Currently my code is:

```
private void Btn_VolumeInject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => ButtonHandler("sampleCase");

private async void ButtonHandler(string action, string type = "") {
    switch (action) {
         case "sampleCase":
             foreach (Object o in ObjectList) {
                 if(o.Name == currentObject.Name){    //currentObject is a global that changes depending on what radio button is selected in the winform                             
                     Debug.WriteLine("start " + o.Name + " " + o.IsRunning);
                     o.IsRunning = true;
                     await Task.Run(() => SampleTask());
                     o.IsRunning = false;
                     Debug.WriteLine("end" + o.Name + " " +  o.IsRunning);
                }
           }
           break;
         //more cases for different buttons....
     }
}
```

So in this snippet of code, on the first click the first task starts, on the second click the second task starts. By the time the first task finishes the first objects `IsRunning` goes to false, but the second objects `IsRunning` stays as true and starts again. Is it because it's not thread safe?

The first objects name is `old` and the second objects name is `new`.
`SampleTask()` has been altered to just delay time to see what happens.

The output is:

```
start old False
start new False
end old False
start new True
end new False
end new False
```

Adding

```
if(o.IsRunning){ //prior to the first Debug.WriteLine
    break;
}
```

fixes my problem but I would like to know why the task runs 3 times when I press the button only 2 times.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  We can't tell what your code is doing.  What happened when you debugged your code, stepped through it?

Comment: You need to show the code for the 'more cases' since I presume by second click you mean a different case.

Comment: There isn't anything that stops the user from clicking that button again while it is still wrestling through that ObjectList.  That is not safe.  Set the button's Enabled property to false.  If it still gets stuck then use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to find out what the threads are doing.

Comment: sorry guys, my original post wasn't clear i've edited it to reflect it more

Comment: A quick fix I did was add the line if(o.IsRunning){break;} (prior to Task.Run) which solves the issue but I'd like to know why it runs the task 3 times when I press the button twice

Comment: I'm wondering if your actual on click event is being called multiple times. That can easily happen if you add the event handler more than once. Looking at what you've provided, I can't rule that out.